# CSS putting z-index of text-shadow behind background

Tags: css

After searching the web for other's solutions to coloring half of a character using CSS, I found this: http://jsbin.com/rexoyice/1. After a small adjustment to suit my purposes, I implemented it. I had planned to use text-shadow on this. The shadow covers the "text," which is actually colored by the background. I am a novice at CSS and have no clue how to use z-indexing to put the text-shadow behind the background. I'm open to other solutions that others may come up with if z-indexing isn't the ideal solution.

In the code below, the top line has the shadow applied, while the lower one doesn't.

```css
.HalfColor
{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(0, #7db9e8 50%,#1e5799 50%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    /*^For compatibility*/
    color: transparent;
  /*text-shadow:0 0 0 #0000 !important*/
}

p
{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <b>
      <p class="HalfColor">TEST!</p>
      <br>
      <span class="HalfColor">TEST!</span>
    </b>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use drop-shadow filter instead:

```css
.HalfColor {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(0, #7db9e8 50%, #1e5799 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  /*^For compatibility*/
  color: transparent;
}

p {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 2px #000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <b>
      <p class="HalfColor">TEST!</p>
      <br>
      <span class="HalfColor">TEST!</span>
    </b>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pseudo-elements`

```css
.HalfColor {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(0, #7db9e8 50%, #1e5799 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

p.HalfColor {
  position: relative;
}

p.HalfColor:after {
  content: 'TEST!';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
  z-index: -1;;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <b>
      <p class="HalfColor">TEST!</p>
      <br>
      <span class="HalfColor">TEST!</span>
    </b>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can it be modified to work with whatever I type instead; I noticed you used CSS's "content."